# how docker-machine uses docker api to copy certificates

Tags: ssh, docker, certificate, docker-machine

My question is, as I understand docker-machine uses docker remote API to do whatever it does, for example to regenerate certificates. I have checked docker API but couldn't find how it's possible to send certificates to that machine using only docker api, can someone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The TLS files are hosted locally on the Docker client. For this reason you should protect the files as if they were a root password.

This page will walk you through generating the files needed to negotiate a connection over TLS. Note that the remote daemon must be running TLS.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/

`docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H=$HOST:2376 version`

> Note: Docker over TLS should run on TCP port 2376.
>
> Warning: As shown in the example above, you don’t have to run the
>   docker client with sudo or the docker group when you use certificate
>   authentication. That means anyone with the keys can give any
>   instructions to your Docker daemon, giving them root access to the
>   machine hosting the daemon. Guard these keys as you would a root
>   password!

Comment: Thanks for helping, actually what I wanted to ask is, how does docker-machine manage to change certificate files on docker host? since they are owned by root.